# postgres.exe: why multiple postgres.exe for a single database connection?

Tags: windows, postgresql

I'm using postgresql, and when I start a database connection (using PQconnectdb) I see two new postgres.exe which appear.  In some of my tools, I see three new postgres.exe which appear.

I've read the multiple postgres.exe is normal, as it uses a multi-process architecture instead of a multi-threaded one, but I'm wondering why there are 2 (or 3) of them that start up when I connect to the database.

Comment: Its pretty normal, In windows you can see upto 8 postgres.exe when just starting the server. And when opening each connection, one postgres.exe is newly created. If you want to know more about these look on the below link.  http://www.interdb.jp/pg/pgsql02.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On linux, I see 3 processes:

1. `postgres: logger process`
2. `postgres: writer process`
3. `postgres: stats collector process`

There's also an additional process for each open connection.  Autovacuum will probably similarly occupy one thread per worker, while working.

I imagine the situation is similar in windows.

Comment: There are the process that (on Windows) the postgres service starts.  However, when my software connects to the database, more postgres.exe are spawned.  So the logger/writer/stats collector might be a different thing.

Comment: I should have added that I see 6 postgres.exe processes before my software tries to make any database connection.